# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.Im executing this query in JAVA

Tags: java, sql

Getting this error message and i don't know why:

ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.Im executing this query in JAVA:

```
String query2 = "SELECT  dock_id " +
                "FROM ( " +
                "SELECT  inventory_location_id AS dock_id " +
                "FROM mtl_item_locations " +
                "WHERE organization_id = 402 " +
                "AND subinventory_code = 'me' " +
                "AND inventory_location_type = 1 " +
                "AND NOT EXISTS ( " +
                "SELECT  1 " +
                "FROM wms_dock_appointments_v " +
                "WHERE dock_id = inventory_location_id " +
                "AND ( start_time BETWEEN '30/05/2023' AND '05/06/2023' " +
                "     OR end_time BETWEEN '30/05/2023' AND '05/06/2023' " +
                "     OR '30/05/2023' BETWEEN start_time AND end_time " +
                "     OR '30/05/2023' BETWEEN start_time AND end_time " +
                "             )) " +
                "ORDER BY inventory_location_id  " +
                ") " +
                "WHERE rownum = 1;";

PreparedStatement stmt2 = connection.prepareStatement(query2);
ResultSet rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery();
```

The query by itself works in SQL DEVELOPER but it crashes when doin it in my IDE

Whats wrong here?

Tried so many times without success

Comment: remove the `;` at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reformat it to analyze it better:

```sql
SELECT dock_id FROM 
(
   SELECT inventory_location_id AS dock_id FROM mtl_item_locations 
      WHERE organization_id = 402 AND subinventory_code ='me' AND inventory_location_type = 1 AND 
      NOT EXISTS 
      (
         SELECT 1 FROM wms_dock_appointments_v 
         WHERE dock_id = inventory_location_id AND 
         (
            start_time BETWEEN '30/05/2023' AND '05/06/2023' OR 
            end_time BETWEEN '30/05/2023' AND '05/06/2023' OR 
            '30/05/2023' BETWEEN start_time AND end_time OR 
            '30/05/2023' BETWEEN start_time AND end_time
         )
     ) 
   ORDER BY inventory_location_id
) 
WHERE rownum = 1
```

Removing the `;` is a good idea.
name the subqueries also may help you, if your dbms allow it.

Because the purpose of `SELECT 1 FROM wms_dock_appointments_v` isn't
clear, for example:
what fields can be found in `wms_dock_appointments_v`?
`dock_id`, `inventory_location_id`?

Comment: Thanks Marc, i was able to solve by deleting the ";"